Starting a separate ASP.NET Core process using Task.Run
Background
I'm working on a suite of applications that operate in a localhost network and need to coordinate between each other. There is a Main (currently runs on Windows_ and Mobiles, which operate on iOS and Android. Initially the Main was a WPF app and the Mobile - MAUI apps. I have now migrated the Main app to MAUI as well in order to unify the stack (and fix legacy problems with the WPF implementation). In order to facilitate the communication I need a server and for real-time communication I chose to go with SignalR. To achieve a seamless UX the server needs to start implicitly when the Main program is started. In order to achieve that in a simple manner I simply configure an ASP.NET host and start it within a Task.Run. While I admit this is odd, it worked pretty well with the WPF application.
The Problem
When migrating to a MAUI Main however, I noticed that the SignalR doesn't work as expected. Client -> Hub communication works, however the Hub -> Client communication is failing silently. I.e. a call like:
await _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync(...);

Runs without raising any exceptions but simultaneously produces no results - the equivalent procedures on the client are never invoked. Yes the procedures are registered correctly on the client, I am sure of this because the exact same code that fails in "MAUI context" works as expected when invoked from the "WPF context". My question is why could that be and how I can investigate further.
Notes
I've already head the feedback that ASP.NET hosts aren't supposed to be started using Task.Run or Thread.Start. However I couldn't find an explanation why, so I kept using it and now that it's causing problems, I know how I can solve them, as a simple standalone SignalR Hub process works as expected. For example I could use Process.Start and implementing another layer of communication between the Main and Main.Server. I'm writing here in order to try and understand this phenomenon further. Does anyone have any ideas?

Hi Alex, may I know which kind of signalr you are using ? ASP.NET Core SignalR or ASP.NET SignalR? No matter which signalr you are using , you also can enable the signalr logging feature(ASP.NET Core SignalR , ASP.NET SignalR) to check what happened.

@JasonPan I did enable the debug and I didn't find anything useful in the logs. I'm using Core SignalR, that's build in the framework.

Hi Alex, if we can debug the application, then we can find more. It's hard for us to check this issue now, may I know if you can create a brand new sample for us checking(hide your sensitive information) ?
